# Returning a db query for select options in webform

Tags: 7, hooks

I am trying to return dynamic select options for a webform component.  I have it working to return node titles, but I need to instead return values from a manually created table in the db that is not drupal related.  How would I alter this function to achieve that?

```
function _MY_MODULE_get_rate_options() {
    $nodes = array();
    $select = db_query("MY DB QUERY HERE");
    foreach ($select as $node) {
        $nodes[$node->nid] = $node->title;
    }
    return $nodes; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're creating a select list then you only need two fields from the database, so you can use the excellent [`fetchAllKeyed()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementInterface%3A%3AfetchAllKeyed/7) method of the database query. This will let you get your results in a single line of code:

```
function _MY_MODULE_get_rate_options() {
  return db_query('SELECT id, name FROM {my_table}')->fetchAllKeyed();
}
```

The result is an array keyed by the first field (`id`) with values from the second field (`name`).